# Center of an Image - Windows Phone

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, center

I have a bing map and a pin that is to be pinned on the map. This pin is an image different from the default one. I want this image to be pinned on the map, and It does work until here. But it pins at the left-top of the image. I want it to be pinned thru the center of image. (As if you pin a paper on a pinboard not at the left-top of the paper, just thru the center of paper.)

So how can I set this? VerticalAlignment works for this or not?

Here is my pin image definitions;

```
Image pinimage = new Image();
            pinimage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/killtarget.png", UriKind.Relative));
            pinimage.Width = 64;
            pinimage.Height = 64;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Nokia Map API for Windows Phone 8 and was facing the same issue. I don't know if the same solution will apply to Bing Maps as well but try setting PositionOrigin property of the Pin...it has to be set the following way:-

```
PositionOrigin="0.5,1"
```

the two numbers represent alignment horizontally and vertically so 0.5,1 means Horizontally center and Vertically bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Just a bit of clarity. Windows Phone 8 uses a Microsoft created map control that pulls in Nokia map data. This is exactly what Bing Maps does. There was a bit of a miss communication when they announced the new API.

As for centering the image you can try the position origin, or you can use margins with negative x and y values.